# Why public is not mentioned as a fixed role in system database in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, role, system-tables

While running

```
select * from sys.server_principals
```

for `public` role, in the column `is_fixed_role` is shown 0

[image]
[image]

But the documentation states that it *is* a fixed server role.
[image]

[Documentation Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/server-level-roles?view=sql-server-2017)

Although it is stated that public is a little bit different from other roles because we can assign permissions to it. Anyway it is mentioned as a fixed role.

Can anyone explain this dilemma?

Comment: Just for clarity, `sys.database_principals` shows **database** level things like users, so when checking **server** level things like logins, you should check `sys.server_principals`. That won't help here though, because `public` is also marked as non-fixed there. I'm not sure that it matters - you can't really do anything with the public role whether it's truly fixed or not (e.g. I'm not sure if the docs are wrong or the view is, but I would just post a question on the documentation).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One reason that I can think of `why public is NOT a fixed role - is_fixed_role` is that the permissions can be changed.

From [BOL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/server-level-roles?view=sql-server-2017):

> The permissions that are granted to the fixed server roles (**except public**) cannot be changed.
>
> Only assign public permissions on any object when you want the object to be available to all users.
>
> **Note**: public is implemented differently than other roles, and permissions can be granted, denied, or revoked from the public fixed server roles.

the other fixed server roles permissions cannot be changed.

Answer (score 7):

Public is just an odd duck.

But to apply some retroactive continuity to the documentation you might say that all these built in roles are "fixed" or unchangeable in ways that normal roles are not.  The roles marked as `is_fixed_role` have fixed permissions and changeable membership.  Public has fixed membership (everyone) and changeable permissions.

The column in sys.server_principals and sys.database_principals should be documented to clarify this.